# Why do I get a lifetime error when I use a mutable reference in a struct instead of an immutable reference?

Tags: rust, lifetime

This code works fine ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9669d3ea1996b28d7c353f14cc46297c)):

```
struct F<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

impl<'a> F<'a> {
    fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = F { x: &x };
    let z = y.get();
}
```

But when I change `x` to be a mutable reference instead ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=079da76cdfe3fe30ac6b185404b3a0bd)):

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a mut i32,  // <-- `mut` added
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 3;              // <-- `mut` added
    let y = Foo { x: &mut x };  // <-- `mut` added
    let z = y.get();
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         self.x
  |         ^^^^^^
  |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:6...
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  |      ^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 | /     fn get(&self) -> &'a i32 {
7 | |         self.x
8 | |     }
  | |_____^
```

Why does that happen? As far as I see it, nothing about the lifetimes has changed: all values/references still live exactly as long as in the first code snippet.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think it is important that the second example fails as you couldn't mutate f's x anymore.

Comment: Note: `f` should be `F`, and you can call `y.get()` directly... and I really like this question!

Comment: Wow, took me some time but I think I *finally* understand exactly what was going on here and going down this rabbit hole was really cool. Thanks for the question again!

Answer (score 7):

Why does the Rust compiler reject this implementation of `get`? Because it allows:

The following is a perfectly reasonable `main`, assuming that `get` compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 3;

    let y = Foo { x: &mut x };
    let a = y.get();
    let b = y.x;

    println!("{} {}", a, b);
}
```

Yet if `get` were to compile, this would be fine:

- `a` does not borrow `y` because the lifetime is different
- `b` "consumes" `y` (moving from `y.x`) but we do not reuse it after

So everything is fine, except that we now have a `&i32` and `&mut i32` *both* pointing to `x`.

*Note: to make it compile, you can use `unsafe` inside of `get`: `unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&*self.x) }`; scary, eh?*

---

At the heart of the borrow-checking algorithm is the cornerstone on which Rust's memory safety is built:

> **Aliasing XOR Mutability**

Rust achieves memory safety without garbage collection by guaranteeing that whenever you are modifying something, no observer can have a reference inside that something that could become dangling.

This, in turns, lets us interpret:

- `&T` as an *aliasing reference*; it is `Copy`
- `&mut T` as a *unique reference*; it is NOT `Copy`, as it would violate uniqueness, but it can be moved

This difference saved us here.

Since `&mut T` cannot be copied, the only way to go from `&mut T` to `&T` (or `&mut T`) is to perform a re-borrowing: dereference and take a reference to the result.

This is done implicitly by the compiler. Doing it manually makes for a somewhat better error message:

```
fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a i32 {
    &*self.x
}
```

> ```
> error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
>  --> <anon>:7:9
>   |
> 7 |         &*self.x
>   |         ^^^^^^^^
>   |
> help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn get(&'a self) -> &'a i32
>  --> <anon>:6:5
>   |
> 6 |     fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a i32 {
>   |     ^
> ```

Why cannot it infer a lifetime? Because lifetime of the re-borrow is limited by `'b` but we are requiring a `'a` and there's no relationship between the two!

By the way, this is what is saving us from blunder here, because it ensures that the instance `Foo` *must* be borrowed while the result lives (preventing us to use a mutable reference via `Foo::x`).

Following the compiler hint, and returning `&'b i32` works... and prevents the above `main` from compiling:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b i32 {
        &*self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 3;

    let y = Foo { x: &mut x };
    let a = y.get();
    let b = y.x;

    println!("{} {}", a, b);
}
```

> ```
> error[E0505]: cannot move out of `y.x` because it is borrowed
>   --> <anon>:16:9
>    |
> 15 |     let a = y.get();
>    |             - borrow of `y` occurs here
> 16 |     let b = y.x;
>    |         ^ move out of `y.x` occurs here
> ```

However it lets the first `main` compile without issue:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 3;

    let y = Foo { x: &mut x };
    let z = y.get();

    println!("{}", z);
}
```

Prints `3`.

Comment: Anywhere documented about the "dereference and take a reference to the result" when assigning from `&mut T` to `&T`?

Comment: @updogliu: Not that I know of; but I haven't read the latest version of the Rust book, etc...

Comment: ```let mut_ref_s = &mut String::from("this");
    let sss: &mut String = mut_ref_s; //reborrow from mut_ref_s
    dummy(mut_ref_s); // moving newly reborrowed tmp from mut_ref_s
    let ss = mut_ref_s; // moving mut_ref_s; ```  Anyone helps to explain when the compiler would choose to reborrow or move a mutable reference. Thanks!

Comment: Cause I find very different MIR generated for ss and sss here. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d36c270f1f0ab174f8a42027fae1c5a

Comment: @ZeGao: As you may have noticed, comments just don't support code snippets well; please hope on the chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) or post a new question.